Since upgrade to 24.04.1 LTS, window tiling is wonky
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Since the upgrade to 24.04.1, which may or may not have coincided with other upgrades, I am finding unexpected window tiling behavior that I'd like to crack.
If I have three firefox windows open -- we'll call them StackEx, Shopify and Calendar, if I open another app, tile it to one side and then alt tab to the shopify window, the StackEx window immediately takes the right-hand focus. If I stack StackEx, Shopify and Calendar on the left, click over to the other app, and then try to type in the Shopify window, StackEx will take focus over it.
It's almost like I'm not allowed to have another app open and visible on the screen while I'm using Firefox.
I've documented the same thing with other apps so I don't think it's a Firefox issue. If use alt tab to hop to a Writer window, any other Libre office window that is open pops to the foreground.
I can't find the pattern to it. I'm typing here and then to confirm the behavior I select my password manager. I alt tab so that Shopify is in front. I stop there, and then click in my password manager, and immediately the Stack Exchange window takes focus, hiding the Shopify window that I just brought to the foreground.
It doesn't seem to matter whether I use alt tab (to toggle through all my open windows) or alt ` to toggle through my browser windows, there's always one that keeps stealing focus.
And if I'm filling out multiple fields in the Shopify window, copying and pasting from a document I have open, Firefox will keep bringing the same wrong window (in this case, Stack Ex) to the fore ground, in front of the window where I'm pasting information.
Another example: I launch one app from exposé (for me that's the </kbd), and then use alt tab to pull up a second app. The first app was tiled on the left, the second is on the right. Instead of just seeing the two side by side, a Firefox window takes the left-hand focus.
Has anyone encountered this yet?  I will continue to try to find the pattern, but I notice it most when I'm trying to copy info from an external app (Writer or a password manager) into a Firefox tab.
This behavior has persisted through multiple restarts of my computer.
